# Вот такой коленкор

Tags: этимология

Откуда происходит слово "коленкор"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если верить Гоголю ("Шинель"), коленкор - это хлопчатобумажная ткань.  Вы интересуетесь, откуда взялось название ткани, или как оно попало в эту поговорку?

Одна из версий - [здесь](http://www.gramma.ru/ARRM/?RG1=11&flag=1&RG2=all&page=36&PHPSESSID=4172b9e6bee814ce8ee0a224b195cfd3) (№ 4419)

Comment: Конечно, мне интересно, как слово попало в поговорку.

Comment: А ссылку Вы посмотрели? Там, правда,немного другой вариант, "другой коленкор", но это близко по смыслу.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, тут речь о коленкоровых книжных обложках. "Другой коленкор" — то есть, другой внешний вид, другая обложка.

Comment: Хорошая идея!

Answer (score 0):

Слово коленкор происходит, вероятно, из франц. саlеnсаr "ситец, ост-индская, также персидская хлопчатобумажная набивная ткань" (с XVIII в.), которое объясняют из перс. kalamkar (Фасмер)

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой коленкор, другой коленкор.

**А что такое коленкор?**

В XVIII-XIX вв. оно означало **недорогую плотную хлопчатобумажную ткань миткаль.** Она представляла собой полуфабрикат, из которого впоследствии производили **ситец, муслин, обивочные и постельные ткани** с рисунком или без него.
Кроме того, миткаль и сегодня идет на изготовление **клеенки и дерматина,** поэтому оба эти слова нередко употребляют в качестве синонимов коленкора.

Итак,  коленкор – **это гладкокрашеная жесткая хлопчатобумажная ткань с полотняным переплетением**. Ее используются в **полиграфической промышленности и швейном производстве в качестве прокладок в одежде**.
http://zna4enie.ru/opredelenie/drugoj-kolenkor-znachenie-frazeologizma.html

**Во фразеологических оборотах**  коленкор можно считать   **основой  вопроса.** Когда говорящий раскрывает внутреннее содержание предмета, то он делает этот вывод: ***вот такой коленкор.***

Если меняется основа (**другой коленкор**), то и предмет видится другим.